# Unresponsive UI interface between Service and Activity

Tags: java, android, service, interface, android-activity

I have a service extended class that responsible for running in the background.
well, in my cases, everytime the service has received an update it must pass a message to the running activity so that the activity UI would be updated too.

So, I'm using TabActivity for example: Main.java, and within a tab of Main.java there's an activity called Contact.java.

I'm following foreground service samples from google to make the service, and on Main.java I bind the service:

```
// Reference to the service
public static EmasService serviceBinder;

// Handles the connection between the service and activity
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
    // Called when the connection is made.
        serviceBinder = ((EmasService.EmasBinder)service).getService();
        Log.v("Main", "onServiceConnected");
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
    // Received when the service unexpectedly disconnects.
        serviceBinder = null;
        Main.this.stopService(serviceIntent);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service disconnected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};
```

and I define Contact.java like this:

```
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Contacts.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("").setIndicator(createTabView(this,"Contact",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.contact_icon)))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

ok, now to get the UI updated I use an interface(newbie problems don't mention it, i know i should use broadcast intent) called ServiceListener.java:

```
public interface ServiceListener {
public void invocation(Message message);
}
```

and then on Contact.java I initialized the listener when reach state onResume:

```
protected void bindInterface() {
    // call bind service instance to setListener this activity
    Main.serviceBinder.setListener(this);
}
```

and on the service it will be initialized:

```
public void setListener(ServiceListener sListener) {
    Log.v(TAG, "setListener");
    //if(listener == null) {
        //this.listener = null;
        this.listener = sListener;
    //}
}
```

and then, everytime it needs to update the UI, it will set new queue on a Vector:

```
lMessage.setData(bundle);
interfaceMessage.add(lMessage);
```

after that, a thread would send the message to the interface one by one:

```
while(listenerIsRun) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(300);
                //Log.v(TAG, "InterfaceQueue: "+interfaceMessage.size());
                if(interfaceMessage.size() > 0) {
                    if(listener != null) {
                        //if(listener instanceof Contacts)
                        listener.invocation(interfaceMessage.get(0));// invoke the message
                        interfaceMessage.remove(0);// don't forget to remove invoked msg
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

and on the Contact.java it'll catch the message like this:

```
public void invocation(Message message) {
    contactHandler.sendMessage(message);
}

// TODO handler which handle ui message from service
private Handler contactHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                // all updating process goes here...
            }
     };
```

well, I assume that this way would make it work easily, but actually it's not!
sometimes it updates the UI, but sometimes it's just unresponsive, WHY?

Please tell me if I miss something or need to add something...

Thanks